# Python KafkaConsumer Unable to receive messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written code in Python to connect to Kafka using KafkaConsumer.

We have 2  different environments for Kafka SIT And UAT.

Everything is working fine till SIT environment. As as soon as I tried connecting to UAT Kafka server the same code is not consuming any messages.

The producer in SIT and UAT environment is same. Also I see in Kafka Control center consumption in bytes but no messages are fetched from UAT ( Offset still remains the same which says 682 messages lagging).

If I switch bootstrap server back to SIT, I start getting messages but the same thing is not happening with UAT bootstrap server.

There is no error and the script compete to success everytime. Here is the code snippet

```
import json
import SSL
from Kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('TopicName', bootstrap_server='ServerName', enable_auto_commit=True, group_id='grpid', consumer_timeout_ms=60000, value_deserializer=json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))

for message in consumer:
    print(str(message.value))

consumer.close()
```

Comment: It is json.loads(m.decode('utf-8'))). Sorry for typo as I added code by my mobile. I have corrected now. Also SIT and UAT are 2 different databases where Kafka messages are published.

Comment: We still don't know what differences are between these clusters. For example, maybe one requires authentication, and the other does not

Comment: Also, are all the partitions for the topic you're using healthy on the clusters?

Comment: Yes they are in healthy status. Producer is able to publish many messages. Could you guide me what exactly I need to check at partition side?

Comment: Describe the topics. Do they have any offline replicas or missing leaders? And do the same with the consumer offsets topic

Comment: I see error message at Kafka side. "Preparing to rebalance group GROUP NAME in state Preparing rebalance with old generation1189(__consumer_offsets-41)(reason removing member kafka-python-2. 0.2-9ceb0a32-9241 on Leave group)(Kafka. Coordinator. Group. GroupCordinator). " Any suggestion on this error message

Comment: That's not an error. Just standard logs when you start and stop any consumer

Comment: I made the infinite for loop by commenting consumer_timeout_ms=60000. Pst this change, I started getting all messages. But now I do not want infinite loop, how should I handle this case? What should be the ideal value for consumer_timeout_ms parameter or if there are no messages then how to exit the loop?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `kafka-python` API. Once you reach `for message in consumer`, then I don't know if there is any way to check if there are going to be more messages or not on the next loop iteration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144298/how-to-close-kafka-consumer-once-all-messages-are-consumed
seems like you want to call `consumer.close()` instead of `KafkaConsumer.close()`